# Can I upload final camera ready version of IEEE International conference to arxiv or academia.edu?

Tags: conference, arxiv, ieee

I have sent final camera ready(CRC) version of accepted papers to respective IEEE Conference organizers. The CRC does not contain copyright or something. They are not yet published into IEEE Xplore.
May I upload final sent versions (preprints) to arxiv or academia.edu? Is it legally acceptable to do it?
Can I upload the preprints to my personal website?

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to read up on the terms and conditions of the conference you've been accepted to (and of the IEEE in general). To the best of my knowledge (which might not be accurate as IANAL), this depends on (1) the conference and (2) whether you've paid for any special rights.